# Sql query for all ascendent of a node

Tags: cte, recursive

I have a table having records as below:

```
ID   Name   parentId
1    A      Null
2    B      1
3    C      Null
4    D      3
5    E      4
```

I need out put in following format

```
ID   Name   ParentName 

 1    A      Null  
 2    B       A
 3    c      Null
 4    D      C
 5    E      C->D
```

I tried with following sql query but not able to get exact output. can anybody help me out

```
With CTE AS
(
   select id, Name, CAST('' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) as Parent from @table
   union All
   select t.Id, t.Name , CTE.Parent+','+CAST(t.Name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) as parents from
   CTE c inner join @table t on t.parentid=c.id and c.parentid is not null
)
select * from cte
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the anchor is set properly (need to be either the roots or the final leaves). Your current anchor set (the first set from the `UNION ALL`) is retrieving all records from the table, not just the *border* ones.

Since your relationships are through parent and not by child, the anchor should contain all records without parents. Then join recursively with each child.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (ID INT, name VARCHAR(1), parentID INT)

INSERT INTO @table
VALUES 
    (1, 'A', NULL),
    (2, 'B', 1),
    (3, 'C', NULL),
    (4, 'D', 3),
    (5, 'E', 4)

;With CTE AS
(
    -- Anchor (all grandfathers)
    SELECT
        ID = T.ID,
        Name = T.Name,
        ParentName = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), NULL) -- Set the data type for the UNION
    FROM
        @table AS T
    WHERE
        T.parentId IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    -- Traverse through each children
    SELECT
        ID = T.ID,
        Name = T.Name,
        ParentName = ISNULL(C.ParentName + ' -> ', '') + C.Name
    FROM
        CTE AS C
        INNER JOIN @table AS T ON C.ID = T.parentId
)
SELECT 
    C.*
FROM 
    cte AS C
ORDER BY
    C.ID
```

Result:

```
ID  Name    ParentName
1   A       NULL
2   B       A
3   C       NULL
4   D       C
5   E       C -> D
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Ezlo for explanation, I realised the mistake in my query.  Your help is really appreciated.